# Newtonsoft - How to set the JsonProperty name with a variable that takes its value from another class

Tags: c#, json.net

```
public class A
{
    public B id { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [JsonProperty("a_variable_with_value_from_class_A")]
    public C id{ get; set; }
}

public class C
{
        
}
```

I would like to set the name of the property field in class B, with a variable that is takes its value from class A. How can be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Well, there is no way of doing that that I can think of. Everything related to class member names as well as attributes *must* be known at compile time. There are other ways to achieve this. You could first deserialize the object to `JObject` by using `JObject.Parse()` and then access the required field dynamically using the value from the field in class A.

Comment: You'd need a custom `ContractResolver`. I can't make an example now but that might guide you to search